# Можно ли вписывать логотип в nav со стороны семантики?

Tags: html, seo

Код:

```
<header>
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="{% url 'articles:index' %}">
        <img src="{% static 'articles/img/logo.png' %}" alt="лого">
        <span>RuArticles</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Новинки</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Темы</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="btn-nav">
      <img src="{% static 'articles/img/pencil.png' %}" alt="карандаш">
      <span>Написать пост</span>
    </a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Влияет ли на семантику, что я вставил лого в nav?

Comment: почему это должно влиять?

Comment: К тому же у вас лого как ссылка, которая является навигацией, почему нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не противоречит [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) и [W3C](https://www.w3.org/). Но, с точки зрения дальнейшего переиспользования, логичнее было бы его в навигацию не включать.

По-сути - это просто ссылка, а не навигация. Навигацию Вы сможете использовать где-то ещё.

А, лого может быть включён в h1, например, если контекст позволяет.

P.S. ...и в div он обёрнут излишне, ИМХО..)